# Trying to implement the Wikitude Cordova plugin with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, wikitude

I am trying to get the [Wikitude Cordova plugin](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap) to work with a blank Ionic project. But not getting a lot of success trying to link all the javascript files etc.

So these are the steps i did:

1. create a new ionic project
2. installed ngCordova
3. added the iOS and android platform
4. did a build of them both
5. installed the Wikitdue Cordova plugin
6. added my license key to the following file WikitudePlugin.js
7. added index.js to the main index.html file in the www folder
8. created in www a folder called views and in there I created another folder called camera
9. in the camera folder I created a js folder and place the js files (marker.js & fromwebservice.js), this folder also contains the following files: cameraview.html and poidetail.html

In the cameraview.html file I call upon the wikitude architect like so:

```
<ion-view view-title="Pub Stop">
  <ion-content class="background">
     <a href="javascript:app.loadARchitectWorld();">Camera</a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And in the poidetail.html I place the following code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Detail">
  <ion-content class="background">

    <h1>test</h1>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When I run it on the phone via Ionic View nothing happens, so I run it in the browser and I get the following error:

[image]

Anybody who was able to successfully integrate the Wikitude plugin with Ionic or sees what I did that went wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the wikitude SDK you need a real device not the browser or emulated device.